# inheriatance problems "ambiguous request"

Tags: c++, ambiguous

I have a problem with inheriatance.
Say i have 4 classes:
base class A,
class B inheriates A,
class C inheriates A,
class BC inheriates B and C

```
class A
{
    public:
        void test()
        {

        }
};

class B :public A
{
};

class C :public A
{
};

class BC :public B,public C
{

};

int main()
{
    BC a;
    a.test();
}
```

Result:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: request for member ‘test’ is ambiguous
note: candidates are: void A::test()
note:                 void A::test()
```

How can i fix this ?
Is this even possible ?
What i want is a single instance of all three classes in BC.

Greetings,
Thalhammer

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem . For `what i want is a single instance of all three classes`, read about a virtual base class.

Comment: Do you want an instance of the classes *in* BC? In that case, you should probably make them members instead of using inheritance.

Comment: Could you please just say "struct" and remove those thousands of noisy and pointless `public`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just discovered [**The Diamond Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem):

Concisely put, non-virtual inheritance implies the creation of a unique base class subobject for each class that inherits from a class. Both `B` and `C` inherit from `A` so that means that they both contain a separate unique `A` subobject. When `BC` finally inherits from `B` and `C`, it will have four subobjects in total: `B::A`, `C::A`, `B`, and `C`.

Calling `BC::test` causes a name lookup for the member `test`. Because `BC` has two `A` subobjects, the result is an ambiguous call because both functions are viable.

Virtual inheritance means that a single base class subobject will be shared amongst every deriving class. A virtual base class is a class that is virtually inherited from. Use the `virtual` specifier to make this work:

```
struct A { };
struct B : virtual A { };
struct C : virtual A { };
struct BC : B, C { };
```

Now that `BC` has only one `A` subobject, the call to `BC::test` will be unambiguous because it is clear to the compiler that that `test` only resides in a single `A`.

Answer (score 1):

See [section 25 on C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/multiple-inheritance.html), with attention to [question 25.8](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-diamond.html).

If you want for class BC to derive just once from class A, you should declare classes B and C to have virtual inheritance from A:

```
class A {};
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public virtual A {};
class BC : public B, public C {};
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The object `a` has *two* subobjects of type `A`, one contained in its `B` base subobject, and one contained in its `C` base subobject. To select which one you want to call, add an intermediate cast:

```
BC a;

static_cast<B &>(a).test();
static_cast<C &>(a).test();
```